# Why I can't see 'wow6432node' when using process.start("regedit.exe")?

Tags: c#, windows, process, 64-bit, regedit

I got some problem..in C#

When I execute `regedit.exe` through my code, in x64 OS System it didn't show

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\'wow6432node'
```

but when i execute `regedit.exe` through `Window Key + R` it show me `wow6432node`

how can i show up `wow6432node`? I don't know how to show up...

here is my code

```
        private void RegeditCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\regedit.exe");
        }
```

or

```
        private void RegeditCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start("regedit.exe");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("regedit.exe");
```

I have tested this code in x64 machine with LinqPad and works.

[Here is orginal topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453384/is-it-possible-to-open-regedit-and-navigate-to-straight-to-a-specific-key-using)

**Edit**

This can be useful 
http://www.rhyous.com/2011/01/24/how-read-the-64-bit-registry-from-a-32-bit-application-or-vice-versa/

Comment: @jeongseok-park I think this is connected with priviliges problem. But I only guess. What type of application you got? web or win forms?

Comment: My allpication type is Winforms.
and I want to see result of 'Process.Start("regedit.exe")' same as 'Window Key +R' but it's different. Execute regedit.exe through 'cmd.exe' also different with 'Window Key + R' result

Comment: cmd.exe result is same as 'process.start' result

Comment: @jeongseok-park Please do this: Open Event viewer in Control Panel -> System and Maintenance -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Applications. After do action check for errors and put stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue:  Check your C# app isn't built for x86.

If a 32bit process executes regedit, then windows will launch the 32bit version of regedit. In this version HKLM\Software actually points to HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node.

If you use start -> run -> regedit (Assuming your running a 64bit version of windows), this will launch the 64bit version of regedit. Now you can see the HKLM (or HKCU) Wow6432Node key exists.